# Rails: validates_timeliness refusing to validate date strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datepicker

Using Rails 3.2 and the `validates_timeliness` gem ~> 3.0 I am running into this problem:

Data as submitted via post to my create method:

`stuff... "purchase_date"=>"08/13/1998", ...`

Result:

`is not a valid date`

I'm using Formtastic and a Javascript date picker to generate semantic forms and the data is making its way into my controller as a string. Could this be the problem or is there something else I've missed?

Comment: Is purchase_date a datetime field on the database?

Comment: Have you checked for the formats that the gem supports? That isn't a valid `dd/mm/yyyy` date even if it is a valid `mm/dd/yyyy` date after all.

Comment: It is a `date` type in the database, but the validation is failing prior to its hitting the database.

Comment: I should add that I have the line `config.parser.add_formats(:date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')` in the initializer. This should specify that the parser recognizes the date as valid, right?

Answer (score 1):

So, in case anyone else runs into this, there is an initializer created when you bootstrap `validates_timeliness` called `validates_timeliness.rb`. Following @mu_is_too_short's lead, I added the following two lines to this file:

`config.use_plugin_parser = true
config.parser.add_formats(:date, 'mm[/-]dd[/-]yyyy')`

The result of these was to allow US dates to be recognized, separated by either hyphens or slashes. ISO dates are automatically recognized by the parser.